# What is the justification for using the sample mean in confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem, consistency

In the set-up for the classical CLT we have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\to^d N(0,1)$$

as $n\to \infty$, which gives rise to the $1-\alpha$ asymptotic confidence interval formula for $\bar{X}_n$:

$$[\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2},\mu+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2}]$$

In practice $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown, and so we replace those quantities with the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ and the sample standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$  respectively.

My question is what is the rigorous justification for this?

Since the sample standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ is a consistent estimator for $\sigma$, an application of Slutsky theorem gives

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\hat{\sigma}}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\to^d N(0,1)$$

so I understand that replacing  $\sigma$ with $\hat{\sigma}$  is justified. However the result

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\hat{\sigma}}(\bar{X}_n-\hat{\mu})\to^d N(0,1)$$ is clearly false, and in fact

$$P(\bar{X}_n \in [\hat{\mu}-\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2},\hat{\mu}+\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2}])=1$$ for all $n$.

Am I missing someting?

Comment: The part that is "clearly false"  and its sequel are irrelevant, because the defining condition for a confidence interval is that it cover the *true* mean, not the estimated one.

Comment: @whuber Yes you are right. I messed up the definition of a confidence interval...

Comment: Your first "confidence" interval actually is a _probability_ interval, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371067/trouble-relating-the-central-limit-theorem-to-confidence-intervals?rq=1). I can't get what application of Slutsky theorem you are speaking of, and $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-\mu)/\hat{\sigma}\sim t_{n-1}$. The part that is "clearly false" does not make sense to me, because $\hat\mu=\overline{X}_n$.

Answer (score 0):

As whuber said, the definition of a confidence interval is that it must cover the true mean $\mu$, not the sample mean $\bar{X}_n$.